# Real Adds for Admobs in android

Tags: android

I am always getting the test adds for admobs. i am not seeing any real adds even i am setting the device id for setTestDevices and also  i tried the addTestDevices also
please help me
Thanks in advance
and here is my code..

```
    HashSet<String> hsDevice =  new HashSet<String>();
hsDevice.add(getDeviceIDforAdMob());
adRequest.setTestDevices(hsDevice);
DfpAdView adView = new DfpAdView(Base.this, AdSize.BANNER, baneerID);                   
    adView.loadAd(adRequest);

    public String getDeviceIDforAdMob()
    {
      String aid = Settings.Secure.getString(Base.this.getContentResolver(), "android_id");

     Object obj = null;
      try 
      {
         ((MessageDigest) (obj = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5"))).update( aid.getBytes(), 0, aid.length());
         obj = String.format("%032X", new Object[] { new BigInteger(1,((MessageDigest) obj).digest()) });
      }
      catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException localNoSuchAlgorithmException) 
      {
        obj = aid.substring(0, 32);
      }
      return (String) obj;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To get real ads remove adRequest.setTestDevices(hsDevice); from your code.

Its for development purpose only to get you placeholder ads so you don't accidentally click them.
see https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/best-practices